# What kind of verb is "is" in this sentence?

Tags: verbs, infinitive-vs-gerund, definition

> She is crying for help.

What kind of verb is the verb "is" in this sentence? Whether it is finite or helping verb or both?

Comment: What do you think? What do you think the infinitive is? Also, check verb tenses: present continuous.

Answer (score 2):

It's both.

> She is crying for help.

In the above, "is" is a [finite verb](https://www.thoughtco.com/what-is-a-finite-verb-1690860#:%7E:text=In%20English%20grammar%2C%20a%20finite,sentence%2C%20that%20verb%20is%20finite.) because it is conjugated in agreement with the third-person singular subject "she" and is conjugated in the present tense.

In the above, "is" is also a [helping verb](https://www.grammar-monster.com/glossary/helping_verb.htm), helping the main verb "crying." When "is" (or the verb "be") isn't a helping verb is when it is serving as a linking verb, like in a sentence with a predicate adjective (e.g., She is sad.) and like in a sentence with a predicate nominative (e.g., She is a person crying for help.).

Answer (score 1):

The verb *be* is finite (tensed) because it determines the tense of the clause. In this case, the clause is present tense because the verb *be* inflects for present tense.

The verb *be* is virtually always an auxiliary. It is auxiliary because it is involved in the subject auxiliary inversion: *Is she crying for help?* and can be negated with *Not*: *She isn't crying for help*.